# how to change value of an object in an array in java

Tags: arrays, object

I am currently trying to create a vending machine. In my **VendingMachine** class I have a constructor that takes in 3 parameters. **itemOnSale**, **amount**, and **priceOfItem**. in my **Test**class the vending machines are constructed and stored into an array like this:

```
VendingMachine[] vendingMachineList = new VendingMachine[4];

vendingMachineList[0] = new VendingMachine("Cookies", 20, 3);
vendingMachineList[1] = new VendingMachine("chips", 4, 1);
vendingMachineList[2] = new VendingMachine("Drinks", 9, 2);
vendingMachineList[3] = new VendingMachine();
```

Where the bottom vending machine uses a default constructor I made. However when it comes to the user buying a cookie I need to update that particular vending machines item amount. How can I make it so that I can change the **amount** value only for the item they bought?

these machines are stored in an array as the assignment specifically asks us to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your VendingMachine likely should have a method that allows you to perform that update.
For the sake of providing an example invocation, let us assume the method is called decreaseStock.  If you are the author of the VendingMachine class, you have the ability to create such a method if you have not already.
Invocation of that method specifically for the "Cookies" VendingMachine would look something like:

```
vendingMachineList[0].decreaseStock();
```

Comment: I completely over looked that. Thank you very much its already working now